# winRt Xaml how to make a 3d folder structure

Tags: microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Hi I have an app that needs to display the next pages inside the container in a 3d view like windows. I have attached an Image for the same .

If a design like this is possible any reference material or code piece might help . Thanks

[image: 3d folder]

a replica of this will also work . no need for real images as the image reside with the client. :) ill just go ahead an implement if any xaml help i get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess plane projection can be used for this . Dont know the actual requirements of yours.

```
<Image Source="your image.png">
<Image.Projection>
    <PlaneProjection RotationY="-5" CenterOfRotationX="0.5" />
</Image.Projection>
</Image>
```

In a Grid you can go ahead and place as many images as u want one over the oher and change the rotation Y. Guess it should work

Here's MSDN link

[projections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700359.aspx)

Comment: Thanks some what looks possible with this